# Multi Threading In servlets

Tags: java, multithreading

I am fairly new to servlets in Java. I have a servlet in which I am collecting information through calling several REST API, which work sequentially. But its taking a lot of time since I have a list of object based on which other REST api's are being called . But if I have a large list then , its taking lot of time to execute. Hence, how can I introduce dynamic threads for each member of the list in order to obtain result in lesser response time

```
ArrayList<Object1> newlist ; 
for(Object1 obj : newlist){
 method1(obj); 
}
public void method1(Object obj){
 //Calling other methods
 }
```

Based on the above example I want to initiate multiple different threads for each object of the arraylist, since sequential execution takes time.

Comment: please add example code so we can help

Comment: ArrayList<Object1> newlist ;
for(Object1 obj : newlist){
method1(obj);

}

public void method1(Object obj){
//Caling other methods
}

In such a type of structure I want to initialize parallel execution for each element in the arrayList, how to achieve this.

All these structure are in a servlet.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html, if you need any assistance there are plenty examples on the web, e.g., http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/07/java8-concurrency-tutorial-thread-executor-examples/